# Nginx as a layer for tomcat apps

Tags: tomcat, nginx

How can I create nginx config to work together with Tomcat?
I have installed Nginx that works with my PHP apps under ports 80 and 443, I would like to rewrite few domains to bind to the tomcat webapp but the tomcat is running on port 8080 which I want to have still.

What would you reccomend to keep current nginx for php and add rewrite for tomcat?
Eg. example.com:80 should bind ip_of_the_server:8080/PROD/example.com

Br,
WT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old but unanswered. Here is my working copy with SSL/TLS

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}


http {

  upstream jenkins {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name jenkins.somedomain;

      location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

  }

  server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        server_name jenkins.somedomain;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins2.somedomain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins2.somedomain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


        if ($scheme != "https") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        location / {

                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_redirect http:// https://;
                proxy_pass              http://jenkins;
                # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
                # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
                add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.somedomain:50022' always;



      }
  }





   }
}
```